# Which crypto exchanges charge zero maker fees other than GDAX?

Tags: exchange-fees

GDAX charge zero maker fees and I thought it is a common practice until I realise many other exchanges charge a fee around 0.20%. What are other exchanges that has zero maker fees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to this list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_exchanges), these exchanges have zero maker's fee:

[GDAX](https://www.gdax.com)
[Coinfloor](https://www.coinfloor.co.uk)
[itBit](https://www.itbit.com)
[Luno](https://www.luno.com)
[Cex.io](https://cex.io)

There are probably more exchanges, but those aren't listed there.